# Como retornar mais de uma Entidade do banco de dados em um LIST?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho duas entidades, *CATEGORIA*  e *TRANSAÇÃO*, no banco também tenho essas duas tabelas.

```
TABELA: CATEGORIA
CHAVE: ID

TABELA: TRANSACAO
CHAVE: CATEGORIA_ID
```

Quando realizado um `select` pelo *entity* realizando um `join`:

```
var _result = (from a in contenxt.TRANSACAO
                          join b in contenxt.CATEGORiAs on a.CATEGORIA_ID equals b.
                          select new
                          {
                             a.ID,
                             b.TIPO,
                             b.ID
                           });
```

Como eu faço pra armazenar isso em um `LIST`?

Gostaria de fazer a manipulação dos dados e não sei como fazer, pois geralmente eu retorno um `LIST` de uma entidade específica, mas não sei fazer quando elas se misturam.

Comment: Existe alguma dificuldade em usar o `.ToList()`? Porque ele é que sempre concretiza em uma lista.

Comment: "Acho" que nao tenho dificuldade, minha dificuldade maior eh como retornar isso, eu digo qual tipo de list eu devo informar no meu metodo. por exemplo:   public List<???> getExample(){  return _result.toList()}    o tipo do List que eu nao estou conseguindo.

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que o .ToList() vai te retornar um tipo anônimo. var _result : List<'a>, que possui 3 propriedades: ID, TIPO e um outro ID, não sei como ele iria concretizar isso.

Se tu colocar o mouse em cima do _result, ele te mostra o tipo e tu poderá criar o método que retorna o tipo certo - exceto se for um tipo anônimo, aí acho que seria de um jeito diferente, um List<Object> ou sei lá.

Comment: @RicardoPieper até onde eu sei é basicamente isto, estou preparando uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas nao estou conseguindo, quando passo o mouse no _result, ele fala que nao pode converter o tipo <AnonymousType#1> em <Object>. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o seu problema seja retornar esse List a partir de um método.

Você está fazendo uma query, cujo tipo é um [tipo anônimo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397696.aspx). Você não pode criar um método que retorna uma lista de um tipo anônimo.

Eu sugiro tu criar uma classe com essas 3 informações que você quer retornar. Aí tu consegue fazer algo assim:

```
List<CategoriaTransacao> tuaLista = (from a in contenxt.TRANSACAO
                      join b in contenxt.CATEGORiAs on a.CATEGORIA_ID equals b.
                      select new CategoriaTransacao
                      {
                         TransacaoId = a.ID,
                         CategoriaTipo = b.TIPO,
                         CategoriaId = b.ID
                       }).ToList();
```

No exemplo acima eu tenho uma classe `CategoriaTransacao` que possui 3 propriedades, equivalentes ao que você quer retornar.

Assim você consegue retornar em um método.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !!! consegui...

Answer (score 2):

De fato é um problema. Como nunca usei nada assim eu não sei se tem uma solução melhor do que as abaixo.

Você pode criar uma classe para receber este novo tipo criado por esta *query*, daí você retornaria `List<Resultado>` se esta classe chamar `Resultado`.

Isto ocorre porque da maneira como está é criando um tipo anônimo para receber o resultado, então você não sabe qual é esse tipo até a execução.

Não precisa ser uma classe mesmo. Pode criar uma uma [tupla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) com a composição deste tipo, aí poderia usar algo assim como `List<Tuple<tipoID, tipoTIPO, tipoID>>`. [C# 7 tem tupla na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) e seu uso costuma ser mais interessante.

Pode declarar isto explicitamente como uma lista e acessar os campos como elementos da lista. Só dá certo se todos os campos forem do mesmo tipo. Claro que dá para usar um `List<object>` para aceitar qualquer tipo mas perde a garantia de tipo.

Por último pode retornar considerar que o retorna da sua função é `List<object>`, afinal o tipo anônimo criado certamente é um `object`. Perde a tipagem forte mas é uma solução. Pode ainda retornar um `List<dynamic>` mas duvido que seja melhor retorna `object`.

Vou usar o exemplo obtido [nessa página](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join) para mostrar o que acontece com o resultado e de que tipos estamos falando:

```
using System.Console;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Customer {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Order {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        // Example customers.
        var customers = new Customer[] {
            new Customer{ID = 5, Name = "Sam"},
            new Customer{ID = 6, Name = "Dave"},
            new Customer{ID = 7, Name = "Julia"},
            new Customer{ID = 8, Name = "Sue"}
        };
    
        // Example orders.
        var orders = new Order[] {
            new Order{ID = 5, Product = "Book"},
            new Order{ID = 6, Product = "Game"},
            new Order{ID = 7, Product = "Computer"},
            new Order{ID = 8, Product = "Shirt"}
        };
    
        // Join on the ID properties.
        var query = from c in customers
                join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
                select new { c.Name, o.Product };

        WriteLine(query.GetType());

        // Display joined groups.
        foreach (var group in query) {
            WriteLine("{0} bought {1}", group.Name, group.Product);
        }
        var lista = query.ToList();
        WriteLine(lista.GetType());
        
        //criando explicitamente uma lista de string (neste caso é possível)
        var query2 = from c in customers
                join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
                select new List<string> { c.Name, o.Product };

        WriteLine(query2.GetType());


        foreach (var group in query2) {
            WriteLine("{0} bought {1}", group[0], group[1]);
        }
        var lista2 = query2.ToList();
        WriteLine(lista2.GetType());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8j1N43). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5XRS2y). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Join.cs).

[Exemplo usando uma classe explícita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465601/221800). Ali conforma o que eu disse.

Ressalto que pode haver solução melhor mas minha falta de experiência me impede de afirmar. Se eu lembrar de algo eu atualizo aqui.