# Como retornar 2 ou mais valores de uma vez em um método?

Tags: c#, .net, funções, return

É comum vermos exemplos de métodos retornando um valor de cada vez. Já vi casos onde é preciso criar uma classe somente para empacotar os dados e poder retornar mais valores.

> Usar as **classes genéricas** seria a melhor forma de retornar 2 ou mais
>   valores de diversos tipos ( int e string) de uma vez em um método?

**Via Objeto ( Acredito não ser recomendado )**

```
public class DoisInteiros
{
     public int Int1 { get; set;}
     public int Int2 { get; set;}
}
public DoisInteiros RetornaDoisInteiros()
{
     return new DoisInteiros() {Int1 = 1; Int2 = 2}

}
```

**Usando Tipos Genéricos**

```
public Tuple<int,string> ReturnsIntAndString()
{
    return new Tuple<int, string>(1,"two");
}
```

Comment: Com o C# 7.0 você pode retornar `tuples` implícitos, de uma forma mais organizada, de uma olhada [neste tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/best-feature-of-c-sharp-7-0-is-tuples-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A classe deve ser criada se fizer sentido, se o conteúdo tem algum significado especial, quando os membros realmente são relacionados e faz parte de um objeto único. Normalmente quando será usado em mais de um lugar. Não crie uma classe só para agrupar um conjunto de valores não relacionados.

A tupla é mais adequada quando só serve para retornar mais de um valor e não produzir uma identidade específica.

Na verdade C# 7 criou um novo sistema de tuplas praticamente tornando obsoleto o uso de `Tuple<>`. E assim as tuplas acabarão sendo usadas para mais coisas.

Muitas vezes onde a criação de uma classe não faz sentido a tupla pode ser usada. Não só porque estamos lidando com valores não relacionados, mas também casos onde o conteúdo agrupado é fugaz e importa mais seus membros do que o conjunto.

Também podemos abusar do uso de tuplas. Tem muito caso que a criação de um objeto nomeado faz mais sentido. E nem estou falando das características óbvias que uma tupla não pode ter por não ser um objeto como comportamento, por exemplo.

Assim:

```
public (int, string) ReturnsIntAndString() => (1, "two");
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
public (int inteiro, string texto) ReturnsIntAndString() => (1, "two");
```

Tem inúmeras vantagens fazer desta forma, incluindo performance e gerenciamento de memória.

Note que nas antigas tuplas os membros tinham nomes `Item1`, `Item2`, etc. Nas novas só terão esses nomes se você não nomear os membros.

A tupla cria um tipo novo anônimo. Ele pode ser usado em qualquer lugar onde caiba um tipo, mas por ser anônimo pode ficar esquisito abusar disto. Com a tupla passamos contar com tipos estruturais. Então duas tuplas independentes que possuam a mesma assinatura (mesma quantidade de de membros com os mesmos tipos na mesma ordem) elas são compatíveis e é como se  fosse uma coisa só.

`out` tenderá se tornar obsoleto também. E `ref` não será usado para retornar mais de um valor. A não ser que precise de performance.

Não recomendo o `KeyValuePair` justamente pelo que informei acima. A semântica é errada. um par de chave e valor é uma especialização de uma tupla que indica ter uma chave e um valor. Se os dados não são relacionados como uma chave e um valor, ele não deve ser usado. Funciona? Claro, mas bons programadores produzem códigos semânticos em primeiro lugar. Obviamente que se tiver mais de dois membros ele não serve.

Meus (vários) testes no código *linkado* na resposta deu consistentemente o melhor resultado para o `out`. Perto esteve a tupla da linguagem e muito pior o `KeyValuePair`.

Um exemplo:

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var (deuCerto, resultado) = "123".TryParseInt32();
        if (deuCerto) Console.WriteLine(resultado);
    }
}

namespace System {
    public static class StringExt {
        public static (bool ok, int result) TryParseInt32(this string text) => (int.TryParse(text, out var result), result);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LvvWqC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/25Xt3Y). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnTupleAndDeconstructing.cs).

Answer (score 8):

De acordo com [este site](https://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values), que compara as "melhores possibilidades" de se retornar 2 ou mais valores em C#, a melhor forma baseado na **performance** é a seguinte:

```
public KeyValuePair<int,string> GetValues() 
{
  return new KeyValuePair<int,string>(10,"xxx");
}
```

Comment: Na verdade `KeyValuePair` não é uma boa ideia. Coloquei sobre o assunto na minha resposta.

Comment: É possível nesse método ao retornar os itens da tupla ao invés de ser a informações propriamente ditas, teria alguma forma de retornar a variável? 

Exemplo: 

public KeyValuePair<int,string> GetValues() 
{
  return new KeyValuePair<int,string>(variavelAqui,"variavelAqui");
}

Answer (score 5):

Tuplas são uma boa ideia. Ainda mais com essa mudança que vem no C# 7, isso vai ficar muito mais fluído e fácil de ler.

Ainda existe a opção de usar um parâmetro `out`, isso se for necessário retornar poucos valores (dois ou três).

Claro que isso depende de contexto, porque semanticamente pode ser errado usar o parâmetro `out`. Neste exemplo em específico (retornar dois inteiros) faria mais sentido usar uma tupla, já num outro caso específico como o `int.TryParse(out val)` já mais adequado o uso do `out`.

Exemplo:

```
public int RetornaInteiros(out int segundoRetorno)
{
    segundoRetorno = 0;
    return 1;
}

//uso
int inteiro2;    
int inteiro1 = RetornaInteiros(out inteiro2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando você quer ter um retorno de mais de um valor, de acordo com as propriedades do **C#**:

Sabemos que é necessário usar mais de um parâmetro de saída,

ou

Optamos por criar mais de uma instância que contém os valores que se deseja retornar.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void GetTwoNumbers(out int number1, out int number2)
    {
        number1 = (int)Math.Pow(2, 2);
        number2 = (int)Math.Pow(3, 2);
    }

    static KeyValuePair<int, int> GetTwoNumbers()
{
    return new KeyValuePair<int, int>((int)Math.Pow(2, 2),
        (int)Math.Pow(3, 2));
}

static void Main()
{
    // Use out parameters for multiple return values.
    int value1;
    int value2;
    GetTwoNumbers(out value1, out value2);
    Console.WriteLine(value1);
    Console.WriteLine(value2);

    // Use struct for multiple return values.
    var pair = GetTwoNumbers();
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
}
}
```

Comment: Na verdade `KeyValuePair` não é uma boa ideia. Coloquei sobre o assunto na minha resposta.